# How to Bind to self in inherited controls?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

The following triggers the converter:

```
<TextBox Header="Quantity"
         Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^[0-9]" extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Forced"
         Background="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValidationConverter}}" />
```

while that doesn't:

```
<TextBox
    x:Class="MyApp.Controls.NumericTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
    xmlns:converters="using:MyApp.Converters"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^[0-9]" extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Forced"
    Background="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValidationConverter}}">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <converters:ValidationConverter x:Key="ValidationConverter"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

when used:

```
<NumericTextBox Header="Quantity" Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

So how to bind to self in an inherited UWP control?

Update: here is a [repro](https://github.com/FrancoisM/InheritingTextBoxRepro)

Comment: Have you checked with `Path=.` ? Are you able to get the `TextBox` inside your `ValidationConverter`?

Comment: When using `NumericTextBox`, I never get into `ValidationConverter`.

Comment: @François, Does the following answer  work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to the parent class like the follow.

```
<TextBox 
 extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationType="Email"
 Background="{Binding Path=(extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid),
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
 Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter},
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I have tested it works, please try this and let me know the result.

---

**Update**

I have checked your code. I found the crux of the problem.

1. Wrong x:class path (`InheritingTextBoxRepro.Control.NumericTextBox->InheritingTextBoxRepro.NumericTextBox`)
2. You have not call `InitializeComponent` that used to initialize xaml.

**Original code**

```
<TextBox
    x:Class="InheritingTextBoxRepro.Control.NumericTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
    xmlns:converters="using:InheritingTextBoxRepro.Converters"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^[0-9]" extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Forced"
    Background="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
        Converter={StaticResource ValidationConverter},
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <converters:ValidationConverter x:Key="ValidationConverter"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>

public sealed partial class NumericTextBox 
{

}
```

**Modified**

```
<TextBox
    x:Class="InheritingTextBoxRepro.NumericTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
    xmlns:converters="using:InheritingTextBoxRepro.Converters"
    extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^[0-9]" extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Forced"
    Background="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
        Converter={StaticResource ValidationConverter},
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <converters:ValidationConverter x:Key="ValidationConverter"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>

public sealed partial class NumericTextBox 
{
    public NumericTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<local:NumericTextBox  Header="Quantity2" Text="{Binding Quantity2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Tks but it doesn't work. And I don't see why it would have anyway. Note that while I tagged the question with WPF to get a broader audience, it is a UWP question.

Comment: @François, Could you share a mini sample for us?

Comment: Added a repro as requested.

Comment: There is indeed a stupid typo when creating the repro! Tks. Moreover, I had to move the converter as an application resources as it wasn't picked up at runtime.